# twinx and twiny from two different axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say I want to plot four sets of axes on the same plot that all share from each other as follows:

ax2 shares a y-axis with ax1. Therefore, I do `ax2 = ax1.twiny()`

ax3 shares a x-axis with ax1. So, I do `ax3 = ax1.twinx()`

Now, ax4 needs to share its x-axis with ax2, but its y-axis with ax3. I know that if it shared both axes with, say, ax2 I could do `ax4 = ax2.twinx().twiny()`, but what do I do where I need it to share each with a different axis?

Comment: [`sharex = ax2, sharey = ax3`](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html)?

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to do what you want with [plt.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

Comment: [This matplotlib gallery example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/shared_axis_demo.html?highlight=sharex) just needs an added `ax4` to be your case, I think.

Comment: Not quite, I'm looking for all four sets of axes on the same subplot... (sorry, don't think that was clear enough in the original question). As it happens, just doing ax3.twiny(), seems to have an accurate enough overlap in the x direction, provided the xlim from ax2 is the same.